# Keep a background image centered even when window is resized

Tags: css, background-image

I have a container div with another div centered inside with a background image.

When I resize the browser window, I want the image to stay centered, even when the width of the browser window is *smaller* than the width of the image.

Here's some code:

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:357px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
.image {
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-GKx0A_H8DGE/Tb9bTBCC5pI/AAAAAAAAANc/jvjcjvuNmGk/s1600/wide-angle-lens-3-1.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:357px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

You can see that when the browser is resized, the image stops "centering" itself after it hits the left side of the screen. What I'd like is to still see the center of the image, with the left side getting clipped off and essentially moving off-screen to the left. Is this possible with just CSS? I'd also be interested in a JS solution if not possible.

Comment: It's not the image that's not staying centered; it's the `div` *containing* the `background-image`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.wrap {
    height: 357px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    background:url('/image.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:357px;
}
```

Comment: Chrome and IE are fine but I couldn't get this to work in firefox: http://ghwd.net/background-image.html. Any idea why?

Comment: @Heraldmonkey That webpage works just fine here in FF6.0.1, FF12.0 and FF14.0.1.

Comment: Found the culprit: FF's navigation toolbar. Apparently I have too many icons up there...if I turn off that toolbar it works properly as you're describing. Thanks